# Unwanted background-color in IE 6

Tags: .net, html, css

I have an image and there is unwanted background-color coming to the image in IE6. Although it looks fine in all others IE6 messes it up with unwanted background-color.Any Ideas??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is the image a transparent PNG image? If so, IE6 does simply not support PNG transparency. There is a JavaScript-based fix available [somewhere](http://homepage.ntlworld.com/bobosola/), if you really need to support IE6. I know that some companies refuse to upgrade IE unless absolutely necessary, but seriously I would no longer support IE6, since the current version is 8 and most people should have 7 by now.

Answer (score 1):

If it is the PNG transparency you can also just save a .jpg ( or .gif ) and select the proper css / background url with any of the following techniques : [css hacks](http://www.webdevout.net/css-hacks)

a simple *. might be enough in this case :)

good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

There are tools for Firefox (like [CSSViewer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2104)) that will show you all styles applied to a certain element. Check it out and see if there is any background-color definition there.

Comment: +1 (However Firebug (http://getfirebug.com/) is definitely the best tool for firefox.)

Comment: Yes, I agree actually. But in my toolkit there are many things that serve many purposes. And this tool helps a lot in situations exactly like this.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your level of experience (Excuse me if I'm underestimating this) but it could also be that you are setting a colour which simply renders differently in the different browsers. Could you post an image or some source explaining what exactly the problem is?

If it's an HTML colour that you are trying to match with an image, it could be easier to set a repeating background of 1 pixel of the image colour in a image file, rather than trying to make the different browsers all render a colour the same way (Not to mention different monitors.)

If I'm way off, I apologize, but in my experience even the most experienced guys sometimes just forget the basics for a moment.

Let me know if you need example code.

Answer (score 0):

This could be the default border that IE places on images.  To find out quickly add the attribute border="0" to your image tag, you can move this to your CSS file if needed.

On a tangent Eric Myer has the daddy of all [CSS reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) files for fixing these types of problems